# Keycloak: how to delete and edit a Group

Tags: java, keycloak

I already tried a bunch of different ways and none of them work.

(First of all im using this, and works with other methods, like create/delete user, create group etc etc)

```
public void startKeycoak(String username, String password) {
    Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(uri)
            .realm(realmName)
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .clientId(client)
            .resteasyClient(
                    new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                            .connectionPoolSize(10).build())
            .build();

    this.kc = kc;
}
```

Problem starts here:

```
public void deleteGroup(String groupName) {
    GroupRepresentation groupRepresentation = kc.realm(realmName)
            .groups()
            .groups()
            .stream()
            .filter(group -> group.getName().equals(groupName)).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);


    //  kc.realm(realmName).groups().group(existingGroups.getName()).remove(); -> Not Working 

  //  boolean a = kc.realm(realmName).groups().groups().remove(groupRepresentation); -> Not Workings - returns a false
}

    public void updateGroup(String newName, String oldName) {
        GroupRepresentation groupRepresentation = kc.realm(realmName)
                .groups()
                .groups()
                .stream()
                .filter(group -> group.getName().equals(oldName)).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);

        //groupRepresentation.setName(newName);  -> 1 - Not working

        //kc.realm(realmName).groups().groups().stream().filter(g -> {  -> 2 - Not Working
            //g.setName(oldName);
            //return false;
        //});
    }
```

Like I said before its working with a lot of methods except those two.

Answer (score 0):

```
kc.realm(realmName).groups().group(groupRepresentation.getId()).remove();
```

try to delete it with the group representation id it works.

Comment: Yap, it was that the solution!  Thks

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this was the solution:

```
public void deleteKeycloakGroup() {
    try {
        GroupRepresentation groupRepresentation = keycloak.realm(realm)
                .groups()
                .groups()
                .stream()
                .filter(xpto -> xpto.getName().equals()).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);

        keycloak.realm(realm).groups().group(groupRepresentation.getId()).remove();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Ignore the .filter()...